# Trouble running startup scripts for containers

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to start three docker containers using docker-compose; a postgresql database, a rest api and a frontend web app.

Previously I had the rest api and the database working perfectly (ran migrations and started the server) but when I wanted to send requests to it from my web app I had trouble connecting to the docker network. All the discussion on the internet was centered around connecting a web app in a container to an api in another container and I didn't find any promising method to connect to it (besides enabling port forwarding in the kernel and exposing myself to the network?) so I just decided to package the web app in a container as well.

My directory structure:

```
ProjectName
|-> projectapi
|-> |-> api.docker
|-> |-> api_start.sh
|-> projectapp
|-> |-> front.docker
|-> |-> front_start.sh
|-> docker-compose.yml
```

The problem is running these startup scripts in the right context (tbh I only need to run a `npm start` and a `python manage.py runserver`).

I can't think of anything I haven't tried, but most of my efforts have been centered around mucking around with paths because for the longest time the issue was not finding the file which I think I have fixed.

This is the docker-compose file, I have tried having all sorts of `command` entries in here to run the desired startup script. I have also used `entrypoint`.

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  db:
    container_name: projectdb
    image: postgres:9.6-alpine
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - projectdb:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: projectdb
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: root
    ports:
      - "8001:5432"

  api:
    container_name: projectapi
    build:
      context: projectapi/
      dockerfile: api.docker
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    expose:
      - "8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: 'projectdb'
      POSTGRES_USER: 'postgres'
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 'root'
      POSTGRES_HOST: 'db'

  front:
    container_name: projectapp
    build:
      context: projectapp/
      dockerfile: front.docker
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    restart:
      always


volumes:
  projectdb:
```

Then there are the Dockerfiles:

front

```
FROM node:8
RUN mkdir /projectapp
COPY $HOSTDIR/package*.json /projectapp/
RUN npm install /projectapp
COPY $HOSTDIR/* /projectapp/
ENTRYPOINT ["npm", "start", "/projectapp"]
```

back

```
FROM python:3.6-slim

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONBUFFERED 1

RUN mkdir /projectapi
COPY $HOSTDIR/requirements.txt /projectapi/
RUN pip install -r /projectapi/requirements.txt
COPY $HOSTDIR/* /projectapi/
CMD ["python", "manage.py", "migrate"]
```

That last line could be `runserver` as well. These are just some examples of the permutations I've gone through but at this point I feel the problem is some conceptual misunderstanding, I've read the docs.

The error messages are all different permutations of not finding the startup script. I think there was a point where I managed to run a startup script and the error became it couldn't find manage.py, at which point I started to look into how to write the script better than just: `python manage.py runserver` but didn't get very far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue but still haven't gotten the network to  work, however that's another question. While I solved the problem with the startup scripts it turned out not to be needed, here's the current state of things:

Directory structure is the same as before.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  db:
    container_name: compdb
    image: postgres:9.6-alpine
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - compdb:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: compdb
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: root
    networks:
      - internal
    ports:
      - "8001:5432"

  api:
    container_name: back
    build:
      context: back/
      dockerfile: api.docker
    entrypoint: ["python", "/back/manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
    networks:
      - internal
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    expose:
      - "8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: 'compdb'
      POSTGRES_USER: 'postgres'
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 'root'
      POSTGRES_HOST: 'db'

  front:
    container_name: front
    build:
      context: front/
      dockerfile: front.docker
    entrypoint: ["npm","start", "--prefix", "/front/"]
    networks:
      - internal
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    expose:
      - "3000"
    depends_on:
      - api
    restart:
      always

  staff:
    container_name: staff
    build:
      context: staff/
      dockerfile: staff.docker
    entrypoint: ["npm","start","--prefix","/staff/"]
    networks:
      - internal
    ports:
      - "3006:3006"
    expose:
      - "3006"
    depends_on:
      - api
    restart:
      always

volumes:
  compdb:

networks:
  internal:
```

front

```
FROM node:8
RUN mkdir /front
COPY package*.json /front/
RUN npm install /front
COPY . /front/
```

back

```
FROM python:3.6-slim

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONBUFFERED 1

RUN mkdir /back
COPY requirements.txt /back/
RUN pip install -r /back/requirements.txt
COPY . /back/
```

staff is similar to front.

The problem was solved by moving the build context into each directory with docker compose. Running startup scripts can be done by changing the entrypoint, however for local development attaching to the container to run migrations or similar is more convenient.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `WORKDIR`. Your current run path doesn't have `manage.py`  -

I tried changing it momentarily -

```
WORKDIR /projectapi
COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . .
CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver"]
```

Comment: I originally had it this way but the workdir seemed to be causing trouble but that was before I changed the context of the build in my compose.yml I'll try this again, thanks.

Comment: Okay so first I just changed the api:
`FROM python:3.6-slim

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONBUFFERED 1

WORKDIR /jafnaback
COPY $HOSTDIR/requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY $HOSTDIR/* ./
CMD ["python", "manage.py", "migrate"]`
and it built with no problem, but then when I also made this WORKDIR command in the app it breaks with the following error: 
`Step 7/8 : COPY $HOSTDIR/* ./
ERROR: Service 'api' failed to build: COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder244752859/me@localhost.4193:1558869859: no such file or directory`

Comment: That's the reason I changed to `RUN mkdir` in the first place, the WORKDIR command was somehow breaking everything.

Comment: What does $HOSTDIR expands to & where is it defined?

Comment: It's the same as skipping it, it's the build context. I solved this I'll post a good answer with my observations once I finish configuring.